# How to remove output limit in FollowRecursive?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, cayley

I'm using a FollowRecursive query to traverse a graph where every node is connected with the predicate "next". The problem is that I can never get more than 99 source => target mappings.

Why is the output limited to only 100 {source: N, Target: M} objects?

The query looks like follows (all variables are of course defined):

```
var chain_pred = "next";
var c1 = g.M().Out(chain_pred);
var start_node = "begin";

g.V(start_node).FollowRecursive(c1).ForEach( function(v){
  g.V(v.id).Out(chain_pred).ForEach( function(t){
    var node = {
      source: v.id,
      target: t.id
    }

    g.Emit(node)
  })
})
```

I wrote the same query with java script recursive calls (in DepthFirstSearch), and it turns out that I can't get more than 100 objects. I can get the expected output till depth-3. At depth 4, I start to lose entire tree branches in the start node. This implies that there is definitely a cap on recursion that kills the query after 100 results.

How to remove this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I answer it anyway:

```
FollowRecursive(c1, -1)
```